# index.html:601 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at showTable (index.html:601) at onload (index.html:614)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a table from json string, but errors are comming, I have use JSON.parse.
I'v removed JSON.parse, but its not working.

```
// javascript function to parse json data//

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
var elements = parsedJson.elements;

    function showTable(){
        console.log("Runn");
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        elements.map(ele => {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML = ele;
            table.appendChild(tr);
        })
    }`
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at 
                       JSON.parse`
 `index.html:599 Runn`
 `index.html:601 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
    `at showTable (index.html:601)`
    `at onload (index.html:614)`

Comment: can you show your json data?

Comment: its in this format, more data is there {
                            "id": 34,
                            "name": "Others (Please specify if any)",
                            "limit": 150000,
                            "tax_type": 34
                        }

Answer (score 0):

is it what you are looking for?

```js
        var json = { "id": 34, "name": "test", "limit": 150000, "tax_type": 34 };

  function showTable(){
   var table = document.getElementById('table');
   var tr = document.createElement("tr");
   for (var key in json) {
     if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = json[key];
      tr.appendChild(td);
     }
   }
   table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  showTable();
```

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```